# how to use JavaScript variables to add a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

Basically what am doing is tring to use a for loop to loop through all elements with a certain class name and user their innerHTML/text content to add an appropriate background-image
since its a photo gallery each div has its image with a name equal to the text content
**but for some reason**
the javascript brings no error but no backgrounds a well and am sure i linked everything well
**and for some other even more odd reason**
the grid works fine in firefox but not in chrome "it doesnt at all"

```js
let imgs=document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");
for(items of imgs){
    let text,x;
    text=items.innerHTML;
    items.style.background="url("+text+".jpg)"
}
```

```css
.photogallery{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(600px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="photogallery" id="np">
    <div class="gallery">IMG 1</div>
     <div class="gallery">IMG 2</div>
     <div class="gallery">IMG 3</div>
     <div class="gallery">IMG 4</div>
     <div class="gallery">IMG 5</div>
</section>
```

Comment: `items.style.background="url('"+text+".jpg')"` <= put quotes around the url string

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure your script has written after html code. Order of html content should be first html and then javascript.
2. In javascript code you should wrap your image URL with a single quotation. Because your URL has white spaces.

For example:

```
let imgs=document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");
for(items of imgs){
    let text,x;
    text=items.innerHTML;
    //In below code use single quote
    items.style.background="url('"+text+".jpg')"
}
```